# There is any way that we can ask question to particular user?

Tags: discussion

What I mean is to I am always asking question to get the solution with reason.

So most of users can give solution as per there understanding but only few people know the exact reason for that particular solution.

Let me give the example:

[overriding/extending price-options.js does not work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152774/overriding-extending-price-options-js-does-not-work/152779#152779)

Has approved answer but there is no reason explained or what is actual problem is explain. That's totally fine.

But if i want to ask this reason to specific user there is any availability  in magento stack exchange ?

Comment: No, there isn't. Use comments, but remember that OP isn't required to answer

Comment: No, you can use comments for that.